# Changes to the bound model not reflecting in controller - Angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a directive to create a custom dropdown in angular JS.

This is how I render it on the UI:

```
<cd-dropdown class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5" id-property="id" value-property="name" placeholder="Select City" on-select-change="onCityChangeSetFirstRegionAsDefault" options="cities_array" selected="city.selected" selection-type="single"></cd-dropdown>
```

It works fine, however, I am trying to get the selected value to reflect in the controller of the view in which the directive is rendered. Let me illustrate -

**GetLocationDetails.html**

```
<cd-dropdown id-property="id" value-property="name" placeholder="Select City" on-select-change="updateCity" options="locationInformation.arrayOfCities" selected="locationInformation.selectedCity" selection-type="single"></cd-dropdown>
```

**GetLocationDetailsCtrl.js**

```
$scope.updateCity = function () {
    console.log($scope.locationInformation.selectedCity); //This is logging the previously selected city (undefined if this is the first selection).
    $scope.locationInformation.selectedRegion = undefined;
};
```

The Directive **CdDropdown.js**

```
careDimensionApplication.directive('cdDropdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            selected: '=',
            onSelectChange: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/common/cd-dropdown.html',
        controller: 'cdDropdownController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.placeholder = attrs.placeholder;
            scope.selectionType = attrs.selectionType;
            scope.valueProperty = attrs.valueProperty;
            scope.idProperty = attrs.idProperty;
            element.on('click', function () {
                scope.bindOptions(scope.options);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The controller of my directive **CdDropdownCtrl.js**

(This is the function that is called when selection is changed in the dropdown)

```
function (selectedItem) {
    popup.dismiss('ok');
    $scope.isValueSelected = selectedItem != undefined;
    if (($scope.selected == undefined && selectedItem != undefined) || (!($scope.selected == undefined && selectedItem == undefined) && $scope.selected[$scope.idProperty] != selectedItem[$scope.idProperty])) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        if ($scope.onSelectionChanged != undefined)
            $scope.onSelectionChanged();
    }
};
```

The problem is that, the `onSelectionChanged()` function that is passed to the directive, (in the example above `updateCity`), prints previously selected city. How do I get the currently selected option there?

Comment: Does onSelectChange: '&' make a difference?

Comment: @gyc - no, its not making any difference.